# How can I make network calls very frequently

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an auto complete feature which means every time the user types a letter, there is a network call to the server, the user can type very quickly and a lot

I usually use thirdparty libraries for network calls but this time they wouldn't work, I need to use AsyncTask by the looks of it.

I read that you can only execute an AsyncTask once. My question is, do I need to create an object of my AsyncTask everytime the user types a letter? is this the best approach?

I am aware of implementing Filterable in my adapter but I need to know about this without Filterable.

Comment: You can use Volley for this.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making network call when user type you can make a network call when user stops typing.
I was implement it for same case as yours.I have a AutocompleteextView and when user type i have to show him list of suggestions, but I call webservice when user stops typing.Below is my example -

```
private final static int DELAY_BEFOR_SEARCH = 2000;
```

Here is Autocomplete TextView Listener -

```
myAutocompleteTV.addTextChangedListener(new SearchListener ());
```

and here is Listener Class -

```
public class SearchListener implements TextWatcher{
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        try{
            mMessageHandler.removeCallbacks(mSearchRunnable);
            if(s.length()>0){
                if(Utility.isNetworkAvailable(mContext)){
                    mMessageHandler.postDelayed(mSearchRunnable, DELAY_BEFOR_SEARCH);
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, getResources().getString(R.string.no_network_message),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and here is Runnable -

```
 Runnable mSearchRunnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
          //TODO call your webservice here 
        }
 }
```

for example if user type want to search 'Android' and he types 'Andr' ans stops typing for 2000 ms then my network call execute.